# FlashLight Widget Crash

Tags: android, widget, led, flashlight

Tried to write widget for my Android app.

**onUpdate:**

```
 @Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
                     int[] appWidgetIds) {


    RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget);
    Intent active = new Intent(context, Widget.class);
    active.setAction(ACTION_WIDGET_RECEIVER);
    active.putExtra("msg", "FLASHLIGHT");

    PendingIntent actionPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, active, 0);

    remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widget_button, actionPendingIntent);
    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds, remoteViews);

}
```

**OnRecive:**

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String msg = "null";

    final String action = intent.getAction();
    if (ACTION_WIDGET_RECEIVER.equals(action)) {
        msg = intent.getStringExtra("msg");
        if (mCamera == null)
        {
            getCamera();
        }

            Toast.makeText(context, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        try
        {
            if(isFlashOn) { turnOffFlash(); }
            else { turnOnFlash(); }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("ERROR --- > ",e.getMessage());
        }


    }
    super.onReceive(context, intent);

}


protected void turnOnFlash()
{
    params = mCamera.getParameters();
    params.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
    mCamera.setParameters(params);
    isFlashOn = true;
}

protected void turnOffFlash()
{
    params = mCamera.getParameters();
    params.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
    mCamera.setParameters(params);
    isFlashOn = false;
}

private void getCamera() {
    if (mCamera == null) {
        try {
            mCamera = Camera.open();
            params = mCamera.getParameters();
        }
        catch (RuntimeException e) {
            Log.e("Camera Error. Failed to Open. Error: ", e.getMessage());
        }
    }

}
```

**Error:**

09-11 14:39:40.595       80-373/? E/QualcommCameraHardware﹕ native_access_parm: error (No such file or directory): fd 30, type 1, length 32, status 0
09-11 14:39:46.255    6096-6096/net.testapp.flashlight E/Camera Error. Failed to Open. Error:﹕ Fail to connect to camera service
09-11 14:39:46.275    6096-6096/net.testapp.flashlight E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver net.testapp.flashlight.Widget: java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2510)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:153)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1323)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5226)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:562)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
        Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
        at android.util.Log.println_native(Native Method)
        at android.util.Log.e(Log.java:231)
        at net.testapp.flashlight.Widget.onReceive(Widget.java:87)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2503)
        ... 10 more
09-11 14:39:48.715      80-6121/? E/mm-camera 8x-vfe﹕ Received VFE Stop ACK!!! ctrlCmd is NULL
09-11 14:40:45.935    5820-5921/com.android.vending E/PlayEventLogger﹕ Upload failed class java.net.UnknownHostException(Unable to resolve host "play.googleapis.com": No address associated with hostname)
09-11 14:41:59.745    6131-6131/com.android.providers.calendar E/Trace﹕ error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
09-11 14:42:01.265    6151-6151/com.cyanogenmod.lockclock E/Trace﹕ error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
09-11 14:42:01.355    6165-6165/com.google.android.calendar E/Trace﹕ error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
09-11 14:45:46.065    5820-5921/com.android.vending E/PlayEventLogger﹕ Upload failed class java.net.UnknownHostException(Unable to resolve host "play.googleapis.com": No address associated with hostname)

Comment: have u added the permissions for camera and your receiver in menifest

Comment: i add 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
and
<receiver android:name=".Widget"  android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
                <action android:name="Widget" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
                android:resource="@xml/widget" />
        </receiver>

Comment: I have 1 button on my Widget. I want turn on and turnt off Flashlight.  How i can do this? Maybe there's another way?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a service, such as follows:

```
Public class widget extends service{

@Override
Public void onCreate{
    Super.on create();
}

@Override
Public void onStart {
    Super.onStart ();

    If(isFlashOn) {
//enter code to open camera and turn on flash
}else{
//enter code to release camera and turn off flash
      Stop self();
   }
}

@Override
Public void onDestroy {
      Super.on destroy();
}

@Override
Public Ibinder onBind {
      Return null;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove "if (camera==null)" statement and just use getCamera(); only as it already has this statement within its method.

Also, add "mCamera.startPreview;"  in turnOnFLash code and stop preview in turnOffFlash code